# Rewriting algebra

Tags: polynomials

I'm working on calculations on polynomials and a paper gives the following algebra step:

$\frac{x^{15} - 1}{x^3 - 1} = x^{12} + x^9 + x^6 + x^3 + 1$

They do not explain how they get to this result, and I can not follow how they did this.

Could someone tell me what step i'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we multiply both sides by $x^3 - 1$, we get $x^{15} - 1 = (x^3 - 1)(x^{12} + x^9 + x^6 + x^3 + 1)$. You can work out the right hand side to see that this is true.

Comment: The problem however is that I don't normally know the right side, this is what has to be derived.

Comment: It is rather well known that $$\frac{x^{an} - 1}{x^a - 1} = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} x^{ai}.$$ Alternatively, you could use long division for polynomials.

Comment: This was not known to me, and exactly the missing link I was looking for. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
The terms of the expression
$$x^{12} + x^9 + x^6 + x^3 + 1$$

are in G.P with common ratio $x^3$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Observe that  the Right Hand Side, is a [Geometric Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) with First term $=1,$ common ratio $=a^3$

Do you know the formula of the [summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series) of its terms

Alternatively, set $a^3=y$  and use $\frac{y^n-1}{y-1}=y^{n-1}+y^{n-2}+\cdots+y+1$ for integer $n\ge1$